# Need help scripting with jar files

Tags: bash, java

I need to launch 17 `.jar` files, one at a time, with a 7 second delay in between each. 
3 hours later, I need to kill all `java` processes, but only those running on surge user. 
3 hours later I need to repeat this process.

So I have something like this in a Windows Batch file.

```
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
timeout /t 10800
taskkill /F /IM java.exe /T
timeout /t 10800

start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7 
start java -Xmx4G -jar C:\Users\surge\Downloads\cooljar.jar
timeout /t 7
```

Now I need it in Linux shell script format.

So I've been using

```
nohup java -jar cooljar.jar && nohup java -jar cooljar.jar && nohup java -jar cooljar.jar.
```

But that does not allow a delay between each launch.

edit: sorry I didn't mention this, the jars have different arguments.

Edit @Byte Commander: I am trying your example like this. It's not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

launch_jars() {

    java -jar cooljar.jar -n 1
    sleep 7
    java -jar cooljar.jar -n 2
    sleep 7
    java -jar cooljar.jar -n 3
    sleep 7
    java -jar cooljar.jar -n 4
    sleep 7
    java -jar cooljar.jar -n 5
    sleep 7

}

while 1 ; do
    launch_jars
    sleep 3h
    killall -u surge java
    sleep 3h
done
```

and I am getting errors:

```
$ bash /home/surge/Downloads/run.sh
/home/surge/Downloads/run.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/surge/Downloads/run.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r'
'home/surge/Downloads/run.sh: line 3: `launch_jars() {
$
```

Comment: The error you show can not be produced by the script you copied above. Please verify that `run.sh` contains exactly the lines above and update your question with the real content.

Comment: hey byte commander! thanks for coming by again. Anyway turns out I had to dos2unix and now it works! Well sort of. It only runs 1 jar, it doesn't launch the next jar D:

Comment: I noticed the console seems to print stuff from the first jar. Like it's primary purpose is to run that one jar, and it wont do anything else.

Comment: Oh oh... I had a typo in my script. The `&` was missing in the end of the `java -jar ...` lines, which means the process was running in foreground instead of being sent to background and allowing the script to continue. Therefore only the first one started. But that still does not explain the syntax error you get.

Comment: the syntax error was from the dos chars. Anyway, works now! thanks! i put & behind the sleep as well, and still works as intented.

Comment: But if you put an `&` behind the sleep, that makes it useless! Sleeping in background makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you launch your Java JAR using `java -jar cooljar.jar`, you could use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

launch_jars() {
    for i in {1..17} ; do
        java -jar cooljar.jar &
        sleep 7
    done
}

while 1 ; do
    launch_jars
    sleep 3h
    killall -u surge java
    sleep 3h
done
```

This defines the function `launch_jars` which launches the same JAR file 17 times in a row with a delay of 7 seconds in between.

It will run an infinite loop of calling that function, waiting 3 hours, killing all `java` processes of user `surge` and waiting 3 more hours.

Copy the script and save it using a text editor like `gedit` as e.g. `jar-launcher.sh`. Then make it executable by running the terminal command

```
chmod +x jar-launcher.sh
```

You can then run the script. To abort it, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: thanks so much!
Hey, what about if 17 jars have different arguments?

Comment: If you need to launch the 17 jars with different arguments or otherwise different commands, it would probably be the easiest way to remove the loop and write all the jar commands followed by a sleep manually, similar to how you did it in your Batch script.

Comment: launch_jars() {
        java -jar -n 2 cooljar.jar
        sleep 7
        java -jar -n 3 cooljar.jar
        sleep 7
}

Like that? or?

Comment: Yes, like that. But note that `java -jar -n 2 cooljar.jar` and `sleep 7` must always either be on separate lines or be separated by a `;`.

Comment: Hey. It says, line 2, $'/ command not found. 
line 3, syntax error near unexpected token `$'{r' line 3, 'launch_jars() {